# How does the heroicons codebase make use of [xx] in a pip install heroicons[django] or heroicons[jinja]?

Tags: python

When I read heroicons python library, I saw there are two ways to install depending on which templates you want to use.

https://github.com/adamchainz/heroicons#jinja-templates

tells me

`python -m pip install heroicons[jinja]`

https://github.com/adamchainz/heroicons#django-templates

tells me

`python -m pip install heroicons[django]`

I understand the purpose broadly. WHich is install based on the choice of template to target.

however, it's the implementation that interests me.

How does the codebase read the installation choice and pick accordingly?

Does this mean there will be two different pypi? But it doesn't seem the case with https://pypi.org/project/heroicons/

Comment: What do you mean by *"Does this mean there will be two different pypi?"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using pip install, `setuptools` is used to also download the required dependencies. The documentation for `setuptools` can be found [here](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies).

The square brackets are a way of defining extra requirements in `setuptools`. As you mentioned, it isn't a separate package in pypi, it is the same package with 2 additional arguments to define additional optional dependencies.

You can see how it is implemented from the [setup.cfg](https://github.com/adamchainz/heroicons/blob/main/setup.cfg) file on github:

```
[options.extras_require]
django =
    django >= 2.2
jinja =
    jinja2 >= 2.8
```

Meaning, in this case: `pip install heroicons[django]` is equivalent to `pip install heroicons django>=2.2`

Answer (score 0):

At the time of setup , there is ho huge difference in both these commands, other than if you specify heroicons[jinja], it will also install  jinja2 >= 2.8 as dependency. This is required to use jinja templates in your project. You can dind that if you install jinja seperately and run pip install heroicons[django], still your jinja templates with heroicons will work.

The run time implementation is different for these templates.  [ [refer here](https://github.com/adamchainz/heroicons/blob/main/src/heroicons/jinja.py) ]